# Fix a prime and let $R=$ {$m/n \in \mathbb Q: m,n \in \mathbb Z$},where $p$ does not divide $n$. Show that $R$ is local.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I already proved $R$ is a subring, but it's the local bit that's giving me trouble. I believe I have it, but I would appreciate a second (or eighth) eye.

Assume $R$ is not local. So $R$ has more than one maximal ideal. Let two of these maximal ideals be $M$ and $N$, $M \neq N$.

Let $(a,b) = \frac{a}{b} \in M$. $p$ does not divide $b$.

$(a,b)$ is contained in an ideal, so it cannot be a unit. So $p$ must divide $a$ (if $p$ doesn't divide $a$, $(b,a) \in R$, and $\frac{a}{b} \frac{b}{a} = 1 \notin M$).

So $(a,b) \in \frac{(p)}{\mathbb Z - (p)}$.

$(p)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z$, so $\frac{(p)}{\mathbb Z - (p)}$ is a maximal ideal of $\frac{\mathbb Z}{\mathbb Z - (p)} = R$ since $p$ is prime.

But every maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z$ is of the form $(q)$, $q$ is prime. So for $N \neq M$, $N = \frac{(q)}{\mathbb Z - (p)}$, $q \neq p$.

But $p$ does not divide $q$, so for any $(nq,b) \in R$, $(b,nq) \in R$, where $nq$ is a multiple of $q$ and $b$ is an integer. So $N = \frac{(q)}{\mathbb Z - (p)}$ are all units, and therefore cannot make up an ideal, maximal or not.

Therefore $M$ is the only maximal ideal of $R$, and $R$ is local.

Comment: With my four eyes, I find the argument OK until "So $(a,b) \in \frac{(p)}{\mathbb Z - (p)}$". After that it's a bit chaotic, but with that sentence you should already be able to conclude. What you have shown is that every proper ideal must be included in $\frac{(p)}{\mathbb Z - (p)}$, and it only remains to say: that thing itself is a proper ideal. Hence it is the unique maximal ideal, because everything else is contained in it.

Comment: Thank you! I will shorten my proof.